# EF Core SQLite - Can't insert NULL into timestamp

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

Using in memory EF Core SQLite for integration tests. When creating an entity with the following column definition:

```
              entity.Property(e => e.TxTimestamp)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .IsRowVersion()
                    .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

Setting with

`TxTimestamp = new byte[8] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }`

I get the following error:

`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: [TableName].TxTimestamp'.`

Any ideas? It is like SQLite isn't inserting the value. Perhaps because with real SQL Server it wouldn't be able to? This model is generated from the Db so I can't just change the model builder definition.